# Drawing line in an image with Canvas

Tags: javascript, node.js, canvas

I have the following code that should draw lines in an image.
My code is:

```js
const { createCanvas } = require('canvas')
const fs = require('fs')

const width = 500
const height = 600

const canvas = createCanvas(width, height)
const ctx = canvas.getContext('2d')

ctx.fillStyle = '#fff'
ctx.fillRect(0, 0, width, height)

ctx.beginPath();
ctx.moveTo(0, 0);

let test = ['53.266179561615,54.9594819545746', '53.266179561615,54.9594819545746']
for (let index = 0; index < test.length; index++) {
    let coordinates = test[index]
    ctx.lineTo(coordinates)
    ctx.stroke()
}


const buffer = canvas.toBuffer('image/png')
fs.writeFileSync('./image.png', buffer)
```

If I write `ctx.lineTo(53.266179561615,54.9594819545746)` it actually works. But my array is long and comes from an input.

Answer (score 0):

```js
let test = ['53.266179561615,54.9594819545746', '53.266179561615,54.9594819545746']
```

Is an array of strings, while the method `ctx.lineTo(x, y)` takes two numbers as its arguments. In your code the following happens:

```
for (let index = 0; index < test.length; index++) {
    let coordinates = test[index] 
    // coordinates is now '53.266179561615,54.9594819545746'
    ctx.lineTo(coordinates) 
    // you call ctx.lineTo('53.266179561615,54.9594819545746'), notice the qoutes.
    // That is a single argument, a string.
...
```

You probably want to use an array of coordinates, so you can call the function correctly.

like this:

```js
let coordinates = [[53.266179561615,54.9594819545746], [53.266179561615,54.9594819545746]];
for (let index = 0; index < coordinates.length; index++) {
    let c = coordinates[index]
    ctx.lineTo(c[0], c[1])
    ctx.stroke()
}
```

Comment: Unfortunately my data comes from DB like that and I can not change it.

Comment: If your DB stores the data as a string, you want to split that string into two strings (each containing only one numer). Then parse the strings back to numbers.

Please include these details in the question!

Answer (score 0):

You have to convert string data to integer. Try this :

```
let test = ['53.266179561615,54.9594819545746', '53.266179561615,54.9594819545746']
for (let index = 0; index < test.length; index++) {
    let str = test[index];
    let coordinates = str.split(',');
    let x = parseInt(coordinates[0])
    let y = parseInt(coordinates[1])
    ctx.lineTo(x, y)
    ctx.stroke()
}
```